# Как добавить двумерный массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Хочу в массив добавить двумерный массив, делаю так:

```
arr.push(["name": nameTask, "status": 0]);
```

но получаю ошибку.

Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь добавить массив это можно. Но то что лежит в массиве это не возможно

так попробуйте

```js
let arr = [];

arr.push(
    [{"name": "nameTask", "status": 0}]
);

console.log(arr)
// или так
arr = [];
arr.push(
    [{"name": "nameTask"}, {"status": 0}]
);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите добавить новый массив в уже существующий, но синтаксис который вы используете применим для объектов, но не массивов.

Приведу пример как можно сделать если Вы хотите добавить данные в формате `entries`, т.е таком, где ключ и значение представлены в виде значений массива под индексами 0 и 1 соответственно:

```js
const array = []

array.push(["name", "Иван"], ["status", 0])

console.log(array)
// [ ["name", "Иван"], ["status", 0] ]

console.log(Object.fromEntries(array))
// {"name": "Иван", "status": 0}
```

В моем примере видно, что данный формат легко может быть конвертирован в объект, при необходимости.

*Если же Вы хотите добавить именно объект, то обратите внимание на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177035/397819) пользователя [@AzizUmarov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/387032/aziz-umarov), где он привел пример как это можно реализовать.*